# Show a count of total number of pins (images) in database on homepage?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

OK - So I have a PINS models that basically allows users to upload images (pins). On the main page of the site I would like to query and show users how many total images have been loaded into the database - I use paperclip and devise: What do I need to do to count and show the total number of Pins ? Thank everyone for taking the time to help with this inquiry :)

Here is my pins model:

```
class Pin < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :description, :image, :tag_list, :image_remote_url 

  has_attached_file :image, styles: { medium: "320x300>"  }
  validates :description, presence: true
  validates :user_id, presence: true

  validates_attachment :image, presence: true,
                            content_type: { content_type: ['image/jpeg', 'image/jpg', 'image/png', 'image/gif', ] },
                            size: { less_than: 100.megabytes }
  belongs_to :user
  has_attached_file :image, styles: { medium: "320x300"}

  def image_remote_url=(url_value)
    self.image = URI.parse(url_value) unless url_value.blank?
    super
  end
  acts_as_taggable

def next_image
  self.class.where('id > ?', self.id).order('id asc').first
end
def previous
  self.class.where('id < ?', self.id).order('id desc').first
end


end
```

and my controller:

```
   class PinsController < ApplicationController
before_filter :authenticate_user!, except: [:show, :index]

  # GET /pins
  # GET /pins.json
  def index


if params[:tag]
  @pins = Pin.tagged_with(params[:tag]).order("created_at desc").paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 100)
else
  @pins = Pin.order("created_at desc").page(params[:page]).per_page(100)

 #respond_to do |format|
      #format.html
      #format.atom



 end 
end 


   # @pins = Pin.all
#end 
#end 


  # GET /pins/1
  # GET /pins/1.json
  def show
    @pin = Pin.find(params[:id])


    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # show.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @pin }

    end
  end

  # GET /pins/new
  # GET /pins/new.json
  def new
    @pin = current_user.pins.new
    @pin_count = Pin.count

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # new.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @pin }
    end
  end


  # GET /pins/1/edit
  def edit
    @pin = current_user.pins.find(params[:id])
  end

  # POST /pins
  # POST /pins.json
  def create
    @pin = current_user.pins.new(params[:pin])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @pin.save
        format.html { redirect_to @pin, notice: 'Pin was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render json: @pin, status: :created, location: @pin }
      else
        format.html { render action: "new" }
        format.json { render json: @pin.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PUT /pins/1
  # PUT /pins/1.json
  def update
    @pin = current_user.pins.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @pin.update_attributes(params[:pin])
        format.html { redirect_to @pin, notice: 'Pin was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { head :no_content }
      else
        format.html { render action: "edit" }
        format.json { render json: @pin.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }

end
  end
end

  # DELETE /pins/1
  # DELETE /pins/1.json
  def destroy
    @pin = current_user.pins.find(params[:id])
    @pin.destroy

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to pins_url }
      format.json { head :no_content }




end

  end
end
#def pin_params
   #params.require(:pin).permit(:description, :image)
#end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're on One month Rails aren't you? Brilliant Tutorial :)

In your Pin Controller include the code in the Action you want (in your example the `show` action):

```
def show
  # your other code here

  @pin_count = Pin.count
  # @count is now available in your view for `show`
end
```

Than you can call in your view => `<%= @pin_count %>`

Comment: hello! Yes! using OMR great tutorial - ok I did what you said and nothing is showing up in my view with <%= @pin_count %>

Comment: I even tried adding a new image to the DB and there is nothing displaying where is placed the code .....

Comment: In Which view are you trying to call the count ?

Comment: Cool so put the code on the **def index** and **def show** action of your controller and then in your view file -> <%= @pin_count %>